# FaceBook API to fetch user's Activity Log

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-rest-api

I need to fetch user's activity log. i tried /{user-id}/activities but its not returning the activity log of an user. I am aware that from "fql" we can fetch the few activities, but FB recently announced they are deprecating the fql's.

I have used notification API but draw back is if the user has already read these notifications, then the API is returning an empty set of data.

Any other way i can fetch the activity log of an user.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no API on Facebook that allows access or retrieval of the user's Activity Log. Furthermore, I doubt there will ever be one as this is the user's private log of information, including things they don't want other user and apps to see.

The only activity support on Facebook is the hobbies / activities the user has added to their profile. This is obviously not what you're after, but I'll detail it anyway. You need to ask for the `user_activities` permission then make a API call to:

```
/me/activities
```

Comment: Its deprecated now.. Is there any other way to get user activity log ? @Niraj Shah

Comment: yep I am also looking for a way to read all activity for the logged-in user, anybody know how?